# using acts as followable gem on tweets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, acts-as-follower

im trying to add acts a follower to my app so a user can follow other users and on the tweets index page only display the current users tweets and the tweets of the people they are following. i currently have a "follow" button on the user show page, but i would expect it to change into "following" on a click, but nothing changes. ive looked at other questions and documentation, but no luck. thank you.

Users show view:

```
<% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
  <%= button_to "Following", {action: "unfollow", id: @user.id}, method: "post", class: "btn btn-secondary btn_unfollow", remote: true %>
<% else current_user != @user %>
  <%= button_to "Follow", {action: "follow", id: @user.id}, method: "post", class: "btn btn-primary btn_follow", remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

Users Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @tweets = @user.tweets.order('created_at DESC')
    authorize @user
  end

  def follow
    @current_user.follow(@user)
    @follow = Follow.find_by(follower: @current_user, followable: @user)
     # @user = User.find(params[:id])
     # current_user.follow(@user)
     #  current_user.follow(@user)
     #  redirect to user_path(@user)
    # respond_to :js
  end

  def unfollow
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @current_user.stop_following(@user)
    # current_user.stop_following(@user)
    # redirect_to user_path(@user)
    # respond_to :js
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :follow
    get :unfollow
  end
end
```

Comment: Your route should also be `post :follow` and `post :unfollow`. You currently have them set as get requests.

Comment: thanks, however it now comes up with "undefined method `follow' for nil:NilClass"  when i click on the follow button. sorry im quite new to this @HamedSaadat

Answer (score 0):

You're adding an ajax response by doing `remote:true`. You need to add a `follow.js.erb` and an `unfollow.js.erb` view that will re-render your partial.

Comment: ah thanks, i've removed it for now and add ajax later when it works. however when i click on the follow button now it comes up with "No route matches [POST] "/users/3/follow"". i changed get to post on follow in the routes, however now it comes up with "undefined method `follow' for nil:NilClass" in my follow method.

Answer (score 0):

Try and remove the `remote: true` part from your view:

```
<% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
  <%= button_to "Following", {action: "unfollow", id: @user.id}, method: "post", class: "btn btn-secondary btn_unfollow" %>
<% elsif current_user != @user %>
  <%= button_to "Follow", {action: "follow", id: @user.id}, method: "post", class: "btn btn-primary btn_follow" %>
<% end %>
```

Add `post` method for both `follow` and `unfollow` actions on `routes.rb`:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    post :follow
    post :unfollow
  end
end
```

and try `current_user` instead of `@current_user` in your `UsersController` if you're using `Devise` as a authentication solution:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @tweets = @user.tweets.order('created_at DESC')
    authorize @user
  end

  def follow
    current_user.follow(@user)
    @follow = Follow.find_by(follower: current_user, followable: @user)
     # @user = User.find(params[:id])
     # current_user.follow(@user)
     #  current_user.follow(@user)
     #  redirect to user_path(@user)
    # respond_to :js
  end

  def unfollow
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    current_user.stop_following(@user)
    # current_user.stop_following(@user)
    # redirect_to user_path(@user)
    # respond_to :js
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks, ive made your changes, however it said "undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass" on the follow method. I then added @user = User.find(params[:id]) to the follow method, which i wasnt sure if that as correct, but it now comes up with  'no implicit conversion of nil into String' with  current_user.follow(@user) in red.